# Access ChangeDetectorRef or ComponentRef of child component from parent component in Angular 6 without injecting it in child component

Tags: angular6

I have a component structure like this in my application -

```
<parentComponent>
    <childComponent [input]="myInput"></childComponent>
</parentComponent>
```

I am using manual change detection for the parent component (due to the size of the application). So in the parent component's ngOnInit, I call the detach method and whenever there are changes to the bindings, I call detectChanges from the parent component. The problem I have is for a few specific changes, I would like to trigger change detection only for the parent component and not for the child component.

```
export class ParentComponent
{
    public myInput: string;
    constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.cdr.detach();
    }

    onSomeChange()
    {
        // I would like to detect changes only for parent 
        // and would like to remove the child from change detection.
        // Something like this.child.cdr.detach(); and then after the 
        // detectChanges call, do this.child.cdr.reattach();
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); 
    }
}
```

I could inject the changeDetectorRef in the constructor of the child and use ViewChild to access the child's cdr. But the problem I have is the child is a third party library that I do not have access to. Another way I could think of is to wrap the third party component in a component of my own and then inject the cdr in the wrapper component.

Like this -

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-wrapper',
  template: '<childComponent [input]="myInput"></childComponent>',
  styleUrls: ['./child-wrapper.css']
})
export class ChildWrapperComponent
{
    @Input() myInput: string;
    constructor(cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
}
```

Is there any other easier way to do this?

Comment: Having a pretty similar issue - have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @tris - Nope. I could not find any clean way to access the changedetector of the child and ended up creating a wrapper component of my own and injecting the change detector in the wrapper.

Comment: As far as I know CDR is some kind of "special injected reference" that is not resolved by the Injector but directly passed to the constructor by reference. Guess one needs to check Angulars code to find a way to achive this - and probably it will be using some hidden, private variable ...

Comment: Yes. That is my understanding as well.